# What is appearance checking in the context of formal grammars?

Tags: turing-machines, automata, context-free, formal-grammars

As I did not find any definition of the term "appearance checking" although it is widely used, I am eager to ask as what it can be defined.
Perfect would be an example using a context free grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appearance checking is a concept in the theory of regulated grammars.

In an ordinary (context-free) grammar we may appay a production to a string if its right-hand side occurs in that string.
So for $\pi: A\to \alpha$ we write $x \Rightarrow_\pi y$ if $x= w_1 A w_2$ and $y = w_1\alpha w_2$.

In a *regulated grammar* we may specify the order in which the productions should occur in the derivation.
As an example, the following context free grammar

$\pi_0: S\to AC$, $\pi_1: A\to aAb$, $\pi_2: C\to cC$, $\pi_3: A\to ab$, $\pi_4: C\to c$

generates the language $\{ a^nb^nc^m \mid m,n\ge 1\}$.
As a regulated grammar we can choose to restrict the sequences of chosen productions to be the (regular) language $\pi_0(\pi_1\pi_2)^*\pi_3\pi_4$. Clearly with this restriction the grammar generates the non context-free language $\{ a^nb^nc^n \mid n\ge 1\}$.

Appearance checking is the notion that we are allowed to skip a production if it cannot be applied. Formally for $\pi: A\to \alpha$ we write $x \Rightarrow^{ac}_\pi y$ if either *(i)* $x$ contains $A$ and $x \Rightarrow_\pi y$ or *(ii)* $x$ does *not* contain $A$ and $x=y$.

How it this useful? It can be used to check that actually all symbols in the string are rewritten before the derivation continues. Consider the productions  $\pi_1: A\to BB$, $\pi_2: A\to X$, $\pi_5: B\to a$ and the "regulator" $\pi_1^*\pi_2\pi_5^*$, and starting with the string $A^n$. In this case the variable $X$ cannot be rewritten. So applying the production $\pi_2$ has to be avoided. This is allowed in *appearance checking mode* when $A$ does not occur in the string. That means we have to rewrite all $A$'s into $B$'s, then we can skip $\pi_2$, and continue rewriting the $B$'s.
This trick can be extended into a grammar that generates $\{a^{2^n} \mid n\ge 0\}$:

$\pi_1: A\to BB$, $\pi_2: A\to X, \pi_3: B\to A$, $\pi_4: B\to X, \pi_5: A\to a$ and "regulator" $(\pi_1^*\pi_2\pi_3^*\pi_4)^* \pi_5^*$

Informally we repeat the following. First $\pi^*_1$ doubles the number of $A$ (temporarily renaming them into $B$'s). We have to rewrite all $A$'s as otherwise we have to apply $\pi_2$ and this will introduce $X$ a letter that cannot be rewritten, so in that case the derivation will not be successful. Similarly $\pi_3^*\pi_4$ will rename all $B$'s into $A$'s effectively doubling the $A$'s. In the final round $\pi_5^*$ renames all $A$'s into the  terminal symbols $a$.

Comment: I have tried to add some informal explanation. Note that $X$ is essential. If no $A$'s are present we can skip $\pi_2$, otherwise we are forced to apply $\pi_2$ by the regulator and $X$ is introduced. As we cannot rewrite $X$ the derivation cannot be successful. Application of $\pi_2$ signals failure to rewrite all $A$'s. Without appearance checking there is no way to force this.